# phantomjs does not capture

Tags: macos, phantomjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I set up a standard yeoman/angular installation on Mac OS X 10.8.3 using npm. I created a new angular project using the yo generator. I installed phantomjs via `npm install -g phantomjs`. I configured karma to unly use phantomjs (all other browsers work fine). When running tests with `grunt test`, phantomjs does not capture at all, even if I set a very long timeout (50000ms). This is the log output:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
DEBUG [reporter]: Using reporter "progress".
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
DEBUG [launcher]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/6j/gz50dm2d3xv1hnz7s1t4lhn40000gp/T/testacular-79891032
DEBUG [launcher]: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs /var/folders/6j/gz50dm2d3xv1hnz7s1t4lhn40000gp/T/testacular-79891032/capture.js
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/node_modules/grunt-karma/node_modules/karma/adapter/lib/jasmine.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/node_modules/grunt-karma/node_modules/karma/adapter/jasmine.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/app/components/angular/angular.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/app/scripts/app.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/app/scripts/controllers/add.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/app/scripts/controllers/main.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/test/spec/controllers/add.js
    /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/test/spec/controllers/main.js
DEBUG [web server]: serving: /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/node_modules/grunt-karma/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
DEBUG [web server]: serving: /Users/alexanderwalter/Development/angularSeed/node_modules/grunt-karma/node_modules/karma/static/testacular.js
DEBUG [karma]: New browser has connected on socket wxBffi5IEZn9zQvoTm0J
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 50000 ms, killing.
DEBUG [launcher]: Process PhantomJS exitted with code 1
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start PhantomJS
```

As I said, it works for all other browsers. Phantomjs also works if I pass it a simple test script which prints hello world to the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and found out it was a problem with nodejs 0.10.8/0.10.9: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/558

Downgrading to nodejs 0.10.7 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to go with node 0.10.11, the Proxy option worked for me (Mac 10.6.8, Karma 0.8.5, and node 0.10.11 or 0.10.7. Node 0.10.8/9/10 didn't work.).

Inside the karma.conf.js file:

```
proxies = {
'/': 'http://localhost:9000'
};
urlRoot = '/__unit/';
```

Inside the karma-e2e.conf.js file:

```
proxies = {
'/': 'http://localhost:9000'
};
urlRoot = '/__e2e/';
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the latest stable version of Node.js. This solved it for me. currently v.10.20.